# What is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm asked to find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n$.

It seems that the sum converges.

I managed to prove that $\forall n,1<\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n<e$

But I don't know how to prove convergence, nor find the value of the limit.

Comment: You can turn this into $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left (\frac{1}{n}\right )^n H_n^{-n}$, but I'm not sure if this is easier.

Comment: What is $H_n^{-n}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475930/how-should-i-calculate-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1n2n3n-nnn.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $( b_{k,n} )_{k, n\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}}$ be the double sequence defined by

$$b_{k,n} = \begin{cases}
0,& n \le k\\
\left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^n,& n \ge k\\
\end{cases}$$
We have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_{k,n}$$
This implies

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n = 1 + \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_{k,n}\tag{*1}
$$

If we fix $k$, then for any $n \ge k$, apply AM $\ge$ GM to the list of numbers
consisting of $n$ copies of $1 - \frac{k}{n}$ and $1$ copy of $1$, we get

$$\left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{n+1}} \le \frac{1}{n+1}\left[n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right) + 1\right] = 1 - \frac{k}{n+1}
\quad\implies\quad b_{k,n} \le b_{k,n+1}
$$

So for each fixed $k$,  $b_{k,n}$ as a sequence of $n$ is non-negative and monotonic increasing. Furthermore, we know

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} b_{k,n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^n
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{k}k}
= \left(\lim_{x\to 0}(1 - x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^k
= e^{-k}$$

By monotone convergence theorem for series${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$, we can exchange the limit and summation in $(*1)$ and get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} b_{k,n}\right)
= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k} = \frac{e}{e-1}$$

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ for the statement and a proof of monotone convergence theorem for series, see [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20100628171504/https://www.math.hmc.edu/%7Ekrieger/analysisresults.pdf) (on web-archive).

Comment: What am I missing here? I thought $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k} =\frac{1}{1-1/e}= \frac{e}{e-1}$, so shouldn't the result be $1+\frac{e}{e-1}$?

Comment: @Scounged $\sum_{k=\color{red}{a}}^\infty x^k = \frac{x^{\color{red}{a}}}{1-x}$ for $|x| < 1$.

Comment: Oh, I missed that $k=1$, and just assumed it was 0 for some reason. My bad.

Comment: The link is not working anymore!

Comment: @Peanut I have replaced the link by the one captured by webarchive.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer changed**

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{\Bbb{N}_0}u_nd\nu=\int_{\Bbb{N}_0}e^{-k}d\nu(k)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}e^{-k}=\frac{e}{e-1}
$$

using the Monotone Convergence Theorem and as achille hui 
 $$u_n=\begin{cases}
0,& n \le k\\
\left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^n,& n \ge k\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Can you expand a little bit more ? I edited things I thought were incorrect.

Comment: @G.T.R I misread the question, sorry. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what $(\frac{n-1}{n})^n$ approaches, and $(\frac{n-2}{n})^n$?

Comment: It should be a comment !

Comment: This hint leads directly to the sum $1+1/e+1/e^2+...$

Comment: Well, not *directly* (there is an exchange of limit and sum which needs some justification) but yes, it does lead to it.

Comment: It's not sufficient a hint. How do you prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n-\frac{1}{e^k}\right) \to 0$ ?

Comment: @G.T.R Monotonicity.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to write the sum as
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \bigg({n - k \over n}\bigg)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \bigg(1 - {k \over n}\bigg)^n \tag 1$$
Note that $\ln (1 - {k \over n}) = -k/n - {1 \over 2}(k/n)^2 - ...$, so we have
$$\ln \bigg(1 - {k \over n}\bigg) < -{k \over n}$$
Exponentiating both sides gives
$$1 - {k \over n} < e^{-{k \over n}}$$
So taking $n$th powers we get
$$\bigg(1 - {k \over n}\bigg)^n < e^{-k} \tag 2$$
Note also that since $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} (1 + t)^{1 \over t} = e$, we also have
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \bigg(1 - {k \over n}\bigg)^n  = \bigg(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \bigg(1 - {k \over n}\bigg)^{n \over k}\bigg)^n$$
$$= e^{-k} \tag 3$$
So the limit of $(1)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ can be evaluated as follows. Fix some $N$.  Then by $(3)$, the sum of the $k = 0$ through $k = N$ terms of the sum $(1)$ goes to $\sum_{k = 0}^N e^{-k}$ as $n$ goes to infinity, while by $(2)$ for any $n > N$ the sum of the remaining terms is between $0$ and
$\sum_{k = N +1}^{\infty} e^{-k} = {\displaystyle {e^{-N - 1} \over 1 - {1 \over e}}}$. 
Hence we have
$$ \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n \bigg({n - k \over n}\bigg)^n \leq 
\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^N \bigg({n - k \over n}\bigg)^n + {e^{-N - 1} \over 1 - {1 \over e}}$$
$$ = \sum_{k = 0}^N e^{-k} + {e^{-N - 1} \over 1 - {1 \over e}}$$
$$\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n \bigg({n - k \over n}\bigg)^n \geq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^N \bigg({n - k \over n}\bigg)^n$$
$$\geq 
 \sum_{k = 0}^N e^{-k} $$
Letting $N$ go to $\infty$ we get
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n \bigg({n - k \over n}\bigg)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty e^{-k} $$
$$={1 \over 1 - {1 \over e}}$$

Comment: I think your proof is flawed. First you fix some $N$ that does not depend on $N$, and then you set $N=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.

Comment: I botched the end there, this should correct it.