# How can I find the limit without using a closed form expression

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to evaluate this limit without using the closed form expression for the sum of natural numbers raised to $k$th power.  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{ 1^n +2^n+\cdots +n^n}{n^n}$$

So far I have tried l'Hôpital which complicates it rather than simplifying and Cesaro Stolz doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Might be related. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150391/evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac-sum-k-1n-kmnm1

Comment: @frank000 1. That might constitute a duplicate. 2. How did you find that so quickly? I need to learn the secret. (serious question) :)

Comment: Would the double limits be equal  when replacing m by n?

Comment: @probablyme I google $1^k+2^k+...+n^k$ and found it but as the answer suggest those questions are quite different actually.

Comment: @frank000 Yes, I see the difference. I just glanced. Did you google with plain text 1^k+2^k+...+n^k?

Comment: @probablyme Yes.

Comment: @frank000 Oooo, ok, thanks!

Comment: You can search on this site for https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22\frac{1^n%2B2^n%2B%22+%22n^n}{n^n}%22 to find duplicates and directly related problems.

Comment: @LutzL: Nice find.

Comment: @LutzL: I have used up my supply of nice/awesome comments for the day :-).

Comment: @deleters : It seems you do not know your limits!!  We do not need spoilers on this website!!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: What you call your answer provides no additional information whatsoever (the OP has mentioned that they have already considered l'Hôpital). When asked for hints (by other high reputation users) as to how one can apply l'Hôpital in this case you side step by suggesting that others look at your other answers. I looked at over 100 of your answers, and searched, but found nothing dealing with l'Hôpital relevant to this problem. You are a high rep. user with a non answer and refuse to provide any more information elaborating your answer. What do you expect?

Comment: There is also this topic : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927771/what-is-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-left-frackn-rightn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{ 1^n +2^n+\cdots +n^n}{n^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^n}{n^n}+\frac{(n-1)^n}{n^n}+\frac{(n-2)^n}{n^n}+\cdots$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}1+(1-1/n)^n+(1-2/n)^n +\cdots=1+e^{-1}+e^{-2}+\cdots$$ 
then one can sum the geometric series.

Comment: Simple and elegant +1 and accepted

Comment: The error of $(1-k/n)^n-e^{-k}=e^{-k}(e^{k+n·\ln(1-k/n)}-1)=e^{-k}·(k^2/n+k·O((k/n)^2)$ does not seem negligible in a sum with growing number of summands.

Comment: I too found every bit of this solution elegant. Right from reversing the series to writing it as a GP of e.

Comment: "Elegant", perhaps, in need of a serious justification for the interversion of limits and summation, no doubt! (This is merely repeating @LutzL's observation above, which, rather amazingly, was not even addressed in the least until now.)

Answer (score 10):

[Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality) says that for $n\ge k$,
$$
\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n
$$
is an increasing sequence. Therefore, by [Monotone Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_series)
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^n
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{n-k}n\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n\\
&\to\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}\\
&=\frac e{e-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: My question is this... What does Bernoulli's inequality and monotone convergence have to do with it? I mean, you could have started from that summation point. The LHS counts upwards and the RHS counts downwards. And from there you could write it as a GP of e.

Comment: One needs to justify the interchange of limit and infinite sum (which is itself a limit) in $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_n(k) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(k)$$ Monotone Convergence does this. To show that the given sequence is Monotonic, we can use Bernoulli.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Using the MCT is a a great idea here.