# How to compute $\lim_{n\to \infty}n\left( \frac{e}{e-1}-\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\right)$?

Tags: calculus

- By reading [What is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927771/what-is-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-left-frackn-rightn) I have already known that
  $$
  \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=\frac{e}{e-1}
  $$
- But then a further question comes, what's
  $\displaystyle{%
  \lim_{n\to \infty}\left\{n\left[{\mathrm{e} \over \mathrm{e} - 1} -
  \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\left(k \over n\right)^{n}\right]\right\}}$ ?.

Can  anyone give some suggestions ?.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n (k/n)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (\frac{n-k}n)^n =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1-\frac{k}n)^n \quad$ !

Comment: A special case of the results obtained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3577271).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the sequence at hand, we can rewrite it into following form
$$
a_n \stackrel{def}{=} n\left[\frac{e}{e-1} - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^n}{n^n}\right]
= n\left[\frac{1}{1-e^{-1}} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\right]
= n\left[\frac{e^{-n}}{1-e^{-1}} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b_{n,k} e^{-k}\right]
$$
where
$$b_{n,k} \stackrel{def}{=} 1 - \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n e^k
$$

For fixed $k$, it is easy to show $b_{n,k} \in [0,1]$ whenever $n > k$. In fact, this sequence monotonically decreases to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Take $\alpha \in (0,\frac13)$ and $K = \lfloor n^\alpha \rfloor$. Since $b_{n,k} \in [0,1]$, we have

$$\left|\sum_{k=K+1}^{n-1} b_{n,k} e^{-k}\right| \le \sum_{k=K+1}^{n-1} e^{-k}
< \sum_{k=K+1}^\infty e^{-k} = \frac{e^{-K}}{e - 1}
$$
From this, we find

$$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^K n b_{n,k} e^{-k} + O( n e^{-n^\alpha} )$$

For $k \le K$, we have

$$\begin{align}
n b_{n,k} &= n(1 - e^{k+n\log(1 - k/n)})
= n\left(1 - e^{-\left(\frac{k^2}{2n} + \frac{k^3}{3n^2} + \cdots\right)}\right)\\
&= n\left(1 - e^{-\frac{k^2}{2n} + O(n^{3\alpha-2})}\right)
= \frac{k^2}{2} + O(n^{3\alpha-1})
\end{align}\tag{*1}
$$
Since as a sequence in $K$, $\sum_{k=0}^K e^{-k}$ is bounded and the error term in RHS of $(*1)$ can be bounded in a manner independent of $k$, we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^K n b_{n,k} e^{-k} = \sum_{k=0}^K \frac{k^2}{2} e^{-k} + O(n^{3\alpha-1})
\quad\implies\quad
 a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n^\alpha \rfloor} \frac{k^2}{2} e^{-k} + O(n^{3\alpha-1})
$$
As a result,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{2} e^{-k}
= \frac{e^{-1}(1+e^{-1})}{2(1-e^{-1})^3}
= \frac{e(e+1)}{2(e-1)^3}
\approx 0.9961473835624938
$$

Comment: Thanks achile!It is clever  for you to  construct the variant number K which is relavent to n ,and evaluate $a_n$by part.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> \begin{equation}
> \lim_{n\to \infty}\braces{n\bracks{{\expo{} \over \expo{} - 1} -
> \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{k \over n}^{n}}}:\ ?
> \label{1}\tag{1}
> \end{equation}

---

The main contribution to the sum $\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{n}}$ ocurrs for values of $\ds{k \approx n}$. In order to derive an asymptotic approximation as
$\ds{n \to \infty}$ we can use the $\color{#f66}{Laplace\ Methods\ for\ Sums}$
as explained in, for example, ( $\color{#44f}{Analytic Combinatorics}$ by *Philippe Flajolet* and *Robert Sedgewick*, page $761$, Cambridge University Press 2009 ).
\begin{align}
\left.{1 \over n^{n}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{n}\,\right\vert_{\ n\ >\ 0} & =
{1 \over n^{n}}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{n - k}^{n} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{1 - {k \over n}}^{n} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}
\exp\pars{n\ln\pars{1 - {k \over n}}}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
\expo{-k}\pars{1 - {k^{2} \over 2n}}  +
\,\mrm{O}\pars{1 \over n^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\expo{} \over \expo{} - 1} -
\color{#f00}{\expo{}\pars{\expo{} + 1} \over 2\pars{\expo{} - 1}^{3}}
\,{1 \over n} +
\,\mrm{O}\pars{1 \over n^{2}}
\end{align}
such that the requested limit, in \eqref{1},  becomes
$$\bbox[15px,#ffe,border:1px groove navy]{\ds{%
\lim_{n\to \infty}\braces{n\bracks{{\expo{} \over \expo{} - 1} -
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{k \over n}^{n}}} =
{\expo{}\pars{\expo{} + 1} \over 2\pars{\expo{} - 1}^{3}}
\approx 0.99614738356249369646\ldots}}
$$