# To evaluate the limit.

Tags: limits

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(\frac1n\right)^n+\left(\frac2n\right)^n+\cdots+\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^n+\left(\frac nn\right)^n\right]$$

I tried to solve this by taking logs on both sides and got this form:
$$\log l = \lim_{n\to\infty} n\log\frac{n!}{n^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\frac{n!}{n^n}$$
After applying limit, $\frac{n!}{n^n}\to0$, so $\log\frac{n!}{n^n}\to-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Then I am stuck. How to solve these type of problems?

Comment: Better formatting please. Also, how did taking log of a sum convert it into a product?

Comment: Yes, I made mistake.

Comment: @Mathsaddict: I just edit your question for a good look. Is I'm  missing anything?

Comment: @Chinnapparaj you didn't miss anything. It looks better now. Thanks for edit.

Comment: It is $lim_{n→∞}\frac{1}{n^2}.\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=∞$

Comment: Actually the question is not edited nicely. It is lim n->∞ [((1/n)^n) + ((2/n)^n)+....+((n/n)^n)]. I am using this site on Android so I have no idea how to edit question to make it look better. Can anyone edit it again, please?

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927771/what-is-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-left-frackn-rightn?rq=1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct version of the question:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=? $$
And this sum converges to
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^n1_{k\leq n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^n1_{k\leq n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-1}},
$$ by (Lebesgue's) dominated convergence theorem or monotone convergence theorem. (Note: $(1-\frac{k}{n})^n \uparrow e^{-k}$ as $n\to \infty$.)

Comment: I didn't understand the transformation from summation(k=1 to n) (k/n)^n to summation(k=0 to ∞) ((n-k)/n)^n

Comment: Sorry that I didn't explain the notation $1_{k\leq n}.$ This 'indicator' function takes value $1$ if $k\leq n$ and $0$ otherwise, so infinite sum is actually calculated only for $0\leq k\leq n$.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: There can be possibly so many different ways to get the limit result of the given sum, but one of the things that you should do first is to investigate the behavior of each term, guess how the total sum would behave and choose/find the appropriate tools/theorems that can show your intuition rigorously.